# simple Granger Casuality test using statsmodels.tsa.grangercausalitytests

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I have several time-series files ( 540 rows x 6 columns ) that i would like to do a simple Granger Casuality test using statsmodels.tsa.grangercausalitytests

```
  from statsmodels.tsa.stattools  import   grangercausalitytests
```

my pandas dataframe ( df) contains the data in the following format

i tried to print the tests using  Open and close columns with following:

```
 print(grangercausalitytests([df[Open], df[Close]], maxlag=15, addconst=True, verbose=True))
```

but it does not work.  Is there a way to perform Granger test on each Column ( Open, High, Low ) with Close  i.e Open and close, High and close , low and close )

```
  Epochtime     Open       High       Low        Close      Vol

  1486094520, 808.11000, 808.11000, 808.11000, 808.11000, 100
  1486094580, 809.45000, 809.45000, 809.45000, 809.45000, 100
  1486094820, 809.99000, 809.99000, 809.99000, 809.99000, 100
  1486095540, 811.45000, 811.45000, 811.45000, 811.45000, 100
  1486095840, 811.30000, 811.30000, 811.01000, 811.01000, 300
  1486095900, 810.76000, 810.76000, 810.76000, 810.76000, 100
  1486096200, 812.00000, 812.00000, 812.00000, 812.00000, 100
```

Comment: "it does not work" is not helpful at all. What's the result, the error message?  Is the data stationary? ...

Answer (score 3):

It requires 2-dimensional array, try this:

```
print(grangercausalitytests(df[['Open', 'Close']], maxlag=15, addconst=True, verbose=True))
```